# user friendly URL in yii2 not working

Tags: url, yii2

user friendly URL in yii2 not working. i can't figure out why.... here is my code from project

eshop/.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URL} !^/(web)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ /web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^fonts/(.*)$ /web/fonts/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ /web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)$ /web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```

eshop/web/.htaccess

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

eshop/config/web

```
....
            'urlManager' => [
                'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                'showScriptName' => false,
                'rules' => [
                    'category/<id:\d+>/page/<page:\d+>' => 'category/view',
                    'category/<id:\d+>' => 'category/view',
                    'product/<id:\d+>' => 'product/view',
                    'search' => 'category/search',
                ],
            ],
    ...
```

it's working without user friendly URL http://yii2.loc/eshop/web/index.php?r=category%2Fview&id=4 but when i use user friendly URL, url become like this http://yii2.loc/eshop/web/category/4 but it's not working. I just got **Object not found!** help me please

Comment: Links don't working. Are you sure that mod_rewrite is enabled for this host?

Comment: i am not sure but i wrote Options +FollowSymLinks and RewriteEngine on

Comment: You can check this by this command: `apache2ctl -M | grep rewrite`

Comment: I am using windows7 and open_server how can i check it out?

Comment: Hmm, from PHP: `var_dump(apache_get_modules());` or check this in `phpinfo();`.